# How to Save Cell Comments in a variable and apply it to a different cell

Tags: excel, vba

So I've been bashing my head against this problem for the past few days and can't find anything to help. I've been trying to copy cell comments from a varying range of cells. These comments would then be added to a new sheet.

Below is a link to a picture of the data that will be captured (apparently I can't post images with a new account). The column on the far right is of interest. The code is supposed to only capture the cell to the left of the tickbox if the tickbox is checked. The entire process is carried out once the button is clicked.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ShixX3w.png]

The code that I think is the problem is below:

```
Dim start_tests As Long 'start of test selection
    start_tests = 2
Dim end_tests As Long 'end of test selection
    end_tests = 100

Dim tests_used(200) As Variant
Dim tests_indent(200) As Variant
Dim tests_font(200) As Variant
Dim tests_comments(20000) As Variant

'Saving the selected tests to an array
no_act_tests = 1
For i = start_tests To (end_tests)
    If Range("N" & i) = True Then
        tests_used(no_act_tests) = Range("M" & i)
        tests_indent(no_act_tests) = Range("M" & i).IndentLevel
        tests_font(no_act_tests) = Range("M" & i).Font.FontStyle
        'Range("M" & i).Select
        'tests_comments(no_act_tests) = Range("M" & i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments).Select
        tests_comments(no_act_tests) = Range("M" & i).Comment.Text '<- Problem Code
        no_act_tests = no_act_tests + 1
    End If
Next i
no_act_tests = no_act_tests - 1
```

So all of that was done to hopefully save each cell's comment to an array for later use. Next a new sheet is created and the column can start being populated. The code below shows what I would use to populate the cell's comments:

```
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Creating New Tab~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = tab_name_desk
End With
End With

 '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Printing Template~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
With Worksheets(tab_name_desk)

  .Range("A1").Value = "Browser:"
  .Range("A2").Value = "Resolution:"
  .Range("A3").Value = "Page URL:"
  .Range("B3").Value = url_name

  'displaying all the tests to be done in the first column
  For i = 1 To no_act_tests
    .Range("A" & i + 3).Value = tests_used(i)
    .Range("A" & i + 3).IndentLevel = tests_indent(i)
    .Range("A" & i + 3).Font.FontStyle = tests_font(i)
    'With .Range("A" & i + 3).AddComment
        .Range("A" & i + 3).AddComment.Visible = False
        .Range("A" & i + 3).AddComment = tests_comments(i)
    'End With
  Next i
```

The full code is below. It has all been tested and works fine except for the comment code.

```
Sub Create_Form()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets("Setup")

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Creating Variables~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Dim tab_name As String      'Creates tab_name as a variable
    tab_name = Range("C1").Value     'Stores the value from C1 in the tab_name variable
    tab_name_mobile = tab_name + " - Mobile"
    tab_name_desk = tab_name + " - Desktop"
Dim url_name As String      'Creates url_name as a variable
    url_name = Range("C2").Value     'Stores the value from C2 in the url_name variable


'Indices
Dim start_browse_desk As Long 'start of desktop browser selection
    start_browse_desk = 10
Dim end_browse_desk As Long 'end of desktop browser selection
    end_browse_desk = 14
Dim start_res_desk As Long 'start of desktop resolutions selection
    start_res_desk = 23
Dim end_res_desk As Long 'end of desktop resolutions selection
    end_res_desk = 38

Dim start_browse_mobile As Long 'start of mobile browser selection
    start_browse_mobile = 45
Dim end_browse_mobile As Long 'end of mobile browser selection
    end_browse_mobile = 52
Dim start_res_mobile As Long 'start of mobile resolutions selection
    start_res_mobile = 63
Dim end_res_mobile As Long 'end of mobile resolutions selection
    end_res_mobile = 70

Dim start_tests As Long 'start of test selection
    start_tests = 2
Dim end_tests As Long 'end of test selection
    end_tests = 100

'Arrays
Dim browsers_used_mobile(25) As Variant
Dim browsers_indent_mobile(25) As Variant
Dim browsers_font_mobile(25) As Variant
Dim res_used_mobile(25) As Variant
Dim res_indent_mobile(25) As Variant
Dim res_font_mobile(25) As Variant

Dim browsers_used_desk(25) As Variant
Dim browsers_indent_desk(25) As Variant
Dim browsers_font_desk(25) As Variant
Dim res_used_desk(25) As Variant
Dim res_indent_desk(25) As Variant
Dim res_font_desk(25) As Variant

Dim tests_used(200) As Variant
Dim tests_indent(200) As Variant
Dim tests_font(200) As Variant
Dim tests_comments(20000) As Variant

 '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Saving Selections~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'Saving the selected desktop browsers to an array
no_act_browsers_desk = 1
For i = start_browse_desk To (end_browse_desk)
    If Range("B" & i) = True Then
        browsers_used_desk(no_act_browsers_desk) = Range("A" & i)
        browsers_indent_desk(no_act_browsers_desk) = Range("A" & i).IndentLevel
        browsers_font_desk(no_act_browsers_desk) = Range("A" & i).Font.FontStyle
        no_act_browsers_desk = no_act_browsers_desk + 1
    End If
Next i
no_act_browsers_desk = no_act_browsers_desk - 1

'Saving the selected desktop resolutions to an array
no_act_res_desk = 1
For i = start_res_desk To (end_res_desk)
    If Range("B" & i) = True Then
        res_used_desk(no_act_res_desk) = Range("A" & i)
        res_indent_desk(no_act_res_desk) = Range("A" & i).IndentLevel
        res_font_desk(no_act_res_desk) = Range("A" & i).Font.FontStyle
        no_act_res_desk = no_act_res_desk + 1
    End If
Next i
no_act_res_desk = no_act_res_desk - 1

'Saving the selected mobile browsers to an array
no_act_browsers_mobile = 1
For i = start_browse_mobile To end_browse_mobile
    If Range("B" & i) = True Then
        browsers_used_mobile(no_act_browsers_mobile) = Range("A" & i)
        browsers_indent_mobile(no_act_browsers_mobile) = Range("A" & i).IndentLevel
        browsers_font_mobile(no_act_browsers_mobile) = Range("A" & i).Font.FontStyle
        no_act_browsers_mobile = no_act_browsers_mobile + 1
    End If
Next i
no_act_browsers_mobile = no_act_browsers_mobile - 1

'Saving the selected mobile resolutions to an array
no_act_res_mobile = 1
For i = start_res_mobile To (end_res_mobile)
    If Range("B" & i) = True Then
        res_used_mobile(no_act_res_mobile) = Range("A" & i)
        res_indent_mobile(no_act_res_mobile) = Range("A" & i).IndentLevel
        res_font_mobile(no_act_res_mobile) = Range("A" & i).Font.FontStyle
        no_act_res_mobile = no_act_res_mobile + 1
    End If
Next i
no_act_res_mobile = no_act_res_mobile - 1

'Saving the selected tests to an array
no_act_tests = 1
For i = start_tests To (end_tests)
    If Range("N" & i) = True Then
        tests_used(no_act_tests) = Range("M" & i)
        tests_indent(no_act_tests) = Range("M" & i).IndentLevel
        tests_font(no_act_tests) = Range("M" & i).Font.FontStyle
        Range("M" & i).Select
        'tests_comments(no_act_tests) = Range("M" & i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments).Select
        tests_comments(no_act_tests) = ActiveCell.Comment.Text
        no_act_tests = no_act_tests + 1
    End If
Next i
no_act_tests = no_act_tests - 1
'ActiveCell.Value = browsers_used(1)


'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Creating New Tab~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = tab_name_desk
End With
End With

 '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Printing Template~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
With Worksheets(tab_name_desk)

.Range("A1").Value = "Browser:"
.Range("A2").Value = "Resolution:"
.Range("A3").Value = "Page URL:"
.Range("B3").Value = url_name

'displaying all the tests to be done in the first column
For i = 1 To no_act_tests
    .Range("A" & i + 3).Value = tests_used(i)
    .Range("A" & i + 3).IndentLevel = tests_indent(i)
    .Range("A" & i + 3).Font.FontStyle = tests_font(i)
    'With .Range("A" & i + 3).AddComment
        .Range("A" & i + 3).AddComment.Visible = False
        .Range("A" & i + 3).AddComment = tests_comments(i)
    'End With
Next i

k = 1
For i = 1 To no_act_browsers_desk
    .Cells(1, ((i - 1) * k) + 2).Value = browsers_used_desk(i) 'displaying the browsers
    .Cells(1, ((i - 1) * k) + 2).IndentLevel = browsers_indent_desk(i)
    .Cells(1, ((i - 1) * k) + 2).Font.FontStyle = browsers_font_desk(i)
    .Range(.Cells(1, ((i - 1) * k) + 2), .Cells(1, ((i - 1) * k) + 1 + no_act_res_desk)).Merge
    k = no_act_res_desk
    For j = 1 To no_act_res_desk
        .Cells(2, ((i - 1) * k) + 1 + j).Value = res_used_desk(j) 'displaying the resolutions
        .Cells(2, ((i - 1) * k) + 1 + j).IndentLevel = res_indent_desk(j)
        .Cells(2, ((i - 1) * k) + 1 + j).Font.FontStyle = res_font_desk(j)
    Next j
Next i
End With

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Formatting~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

With Sheets(Sheets.Count)

  Cells.Select
  Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_desk * no_act_res_desk + 1)).Select
'------------------------------------Conditional Format 'n'------------------

  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_desk * no_act_res_desk + 1)).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=""n"""
  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_desk * no_act_res_desk + 1)).FormatConditions(Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_desk * no_act_res_desk + 1)).FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_desk * no_act_res_desk + 1)).FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_desk * no_act_res_desk + 1)).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

'------------------------------------Conditional Format 'y'------------------

  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_desk * no_act_res_desk + 1)).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=""y"""
  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_desk * no_act_res_desk + 1)).FormatConditions(Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_desk * no_act_res_desk + 1)).FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_desk * no_act_res_desk + 1)).FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_desk * no_act_res_desk + 1)).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    '------------------------------------Freezing Panes-------------------------

  With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 1
    .SplitRow = 3
    .FreezePanes = True
  End With
End With
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Creating New Tab~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = tab_name_mobile
End With
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Printing Template~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
With Worksheets(tab_name_mobile)

  .Range("A1").Value = "Browser:"
  .Range("A2").Value = "Resolution:"
  .Range("A3").Value = "Page URL:"
  .Range("B3").Value = url_name

  'displaying all the tests to be done in the first column
  For i = 1 To no_act_tests
    .Range("A" & i + 3).Value = tests_used(i)
    .Range("A" & i + 3).IndentLevel = tests_indent(i)
    .Range("A" & i + 3).Font.FontStyle = tests_font(i)
    '.Range("A" & i + 3).AddComment.Text = tests_comments(i)
  Next i

  k = 1
  For i = 1 To no_act_browsers_mobile
    .Cells(1, ((i - 1) * k) + 2).Value = browsers_used_mobile(i) 'displaying the browsers
    .Cells(1, ((i - 1) * k) + 2).IndentLevel = browsers_indent_mobile(i)
    .Cells(1, ((i - 1) * k) + 2).Font.FontStyle = browsers_font_mobile(i)
    .Range(.Cells(1, ((i - 1) * k) + 2), .Cells(1, ((i - 1) * k) + 1 + no_act_res_mobile)).Merge
    k = no_act_res_mobile
    For j = 1 To no_act_res_mobile
        .Cells(2, ((i - 1) * k) + 1 + j).Value = res_used_mobile(j) 'displaying the resolutions
        .Cells(2, ((i - 1) * k) + 1 + j).IndentLevel = res_indent_mobile(j)
        .Cells(2, ((i - 1) * k) + 1 + j).Font.FontStyle = res_font_mobile(j)
    Next j
  Next i
End With

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Formatting~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

With Sheets(Sheets.Count)

  Cells.Select
  Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_mobile * no_act_res_mobile + 1)).Select
'------------------------------------Conditional Format 'n'------------------

  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_mobile * no_act_res_mobile + 1)).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=""n"""
  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_mobile * no_act_res_mobile + 1)).FormatConditions(Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_mobile * no_act_res_mobile + 1)).FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_mobile * no_act_res_mobile + 1)).FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_mobile * no_act_res_mobile + 1)).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

'------------------------------------Conditional Format 'y'------------------

  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_mobile * no_act_res_mobile + 1)).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=""y"""
  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_mobile * no_act_res_mobile + 1)).FormatConditions(Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_mobile * no_act_res_mobile + 1)).FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_mobile * no_act_res_mobile + 1)).FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
  Range("B4", .Cells(3 + no_act_tests, no_act_browsers_mobile * no_act_res_mobile + 1)).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
'------------------------------------Freezing Panes-------------------------

  With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 1
    .SplitRow = 3
    .FreezePanes = True
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if there is anything else I should add.

Comment: Have you read the built-in help documentation (F1 key) or online version for the [Comment Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196533.aspx)?  If so, what is different between its example and your code?

Comment: I have read the documentation multiple times but it doesn't give any help with copying the comment. I think I may be missing something to do with objects. The error it pops up with is a Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.